# JQuery, looping through JSON fails

Tags: jquery, json

I've read the other almost exact questions but am still failing miserably. I give.
I've tried every answer here ....

Here's a sample of the json:

```
[{"count":4,"date":"2010-03-02 09:30:00","id":291,"code":"BPT"},
{"count":4,"date":"2010-03-02 10:30:00","id":292,"code":"BPT"},
{"count":3,"date":"2010-03-02 11:30:00","id":293,"code":"BPT"},
{"count":9,"date":"2010-03-02 12:30:00","id":294,"code":"BPT"},
{"count":8,"date":"2010-03-02 13:30:00","id":295,"code":"BPT"},
{"count":8,"date":"2010-03-02 14:30:00","id":296,"code":"BPT"},
{"count":17,"date":"2010-03-02 15:30:00","id":297,"code":"BPT"}]
```

Here's the current blind stab at getting this to loop through each hash in the array:

```
<body>

<div id="junk">
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$.getJSON('bpt.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function() {
        $("#junk").html(this.count + "<br />");
    });
});
</script>

</body>
```

I'm using firebug and I'm not sure where to look. It only prints the first value or key.
Firebug does show that the json is getting parsed correctly.

Comment: Mmh looks ok to me. Are you sure you retrieve the JSON correctly? You can try a normal for loop: `for(var i = 0, l = data.length;i<l:i++) {$("#junk").html(data[i].count + "<br />");}`. What does `console.log(data.length)` or `console.log(data)` give you?

Comment: console says 405, which is exactly what it should be.

Comment: I've looked at the getJSON docs but I'm wondering if getJSON does something to data to sabotage my loop.

Comment: Standard for loop produces the same --- a single iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you want to print each 'count'?
if so, you'll have to use append() instead of html(). html() replaces the entire innerHtml.

```
$("#junk").append(this.count + "<br />");
```

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/Fndmp/

Comment: You beat me to the punch! Thank you! New to JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
$("#junk").append(data[i].date + "<br />");
```

This doesn't.

```
$("#junk").html(this.count + "<br />");
```

I apologize if this was obvious to some of you. First time JQuery guest, long time listener.